# Nearest cities from latitude and longitude in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, geolocation

How to find nearest cities(user location[lat, long]) from latitude and longitude in **PHP Laravel**?

Table Structure :
locations: 'lon, lat'

user location: 'lon, lat'

```
$loc = explode(',', $request->get('location'));

$results = Agent::select(Agent::raw('SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $loc[0] . ') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(' . $loc[1] . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $loc[0] .') ) * sin( radians(lat) ) ) ) AS distance FROM articles HAVING distance < ' . 200 . ' ORDER BY distance') )->get();
$agents =  \App\Agent::
where('name','like','%'.$request->get('text').'%')
->orWhere('manager','like','%'.$request->get('text').'%')
->orWhere('address','like','%'.$request->get('text').'%')
->orWhere('phone','like','%'.$request->get('text').'%')->get();
foreach ($agents as $agent) {
    $agent->location = explode(',', $agent->location);
}
return $agents;
```

Comment: Search https://support.google.com/maps/answer/4610185?hl=en&ref_topic=3092444

Comment: @dilekkoç I don't use Google Map.

Comment: Read the article to learn how to find near by lat and long

Comment: @dilekkoç Plz see the table structure

Comment: What have you tried so far? There should be tons of tutorials about this topic